# Нужно ввести значение переменной с клавиатуры в классе и в основном коде эту переменную добавить в List<>

Tags: c#

У меня есть 4 фигуры (соответственно 4 класса) и нужно каждой фигуре ввести свои значения, чтобы подсчитать площадь. Нужно реализовать ввод с клавиатуры в каждом классе и чтобы в основном коде можно было загрузить в List<> переменную, в которую ввели значение

```
        double area = 0;
        var rect = new List<Rect>();
        var square = new List<Square>();
        var trianagle = new List<Trianagle>();
        var circle = new List<Circle>();

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Выберите фигуру: \n1.Квадрат 2.Прямоугольник 3.Треугольник 4.Круг");
            int selection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (selection)
            {
                case 1:
                    var _square = new Square();
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите сторону квадрата: ");
                    _square.G = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    square.Add(_square);
                    area += _square.S();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    var _rect = new Rect();
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите стороны прямоугольника: ");
                    _rect.A = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    _rect.B = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    rect.Add(_rect);
                    area += _rect.S();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    var _trianagle = new Trianagle();
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите стороны треугольника: ");
                    Console.Write("сторона: ");
                    _trianagle.A = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("сторона: ");
                    _trianagle.B = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("сторона: ");
                    _trianagle.C = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    trianagle.Add(_trianagle);
                    area += _trianagle.S();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    var _circle = new Circle();
                    circle.Add(_circle.R);
                    area += _circle.S();
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели неправильное значение!");
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Желаете повторить? Y/N");
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.N)
            {
                foreach (var i in square)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"квадрат: a = {i.G}, S = {i.S()}");
                }

                foreach (var item in rect)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"прямоугольник: a = {item.A}, b = {item.B} S = {item.S()}");
                }

                foreach (var i in trianagle)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"треугольник: a = {i.A}, b ={i.B} c ={i.C}, S = {i.S()}");
                }

                foreach (var i in circle)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"круг: r = {i.R}, S = {i.S()}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Площадь равна: {area}");
            }

            }

        while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Y);
        }
    }
}
Вот к примеру класс круга, в нем нужно реализовать ввод с клавиатуры для переменной R и в основном коде закинуть эту переменную в list
class Circle
{
    public double R { get; set; }
    public double S()

    {

        Console.WriteLine("Введите радиус круга: ");
        return Math.PI * R * R;

    }
}
```

Comment: Так а в чем проблема то?

Comment: в классе пишу R=convert.toInt32(Console.Readline());
а хочу добавить в лист эту переменную (circle.Add(_circle.R)), но выдает ошибку "Не удается преобразовать из "int" в "Площадь.Circle"

Comment: @user360293 Ну, так у вас `circle` - это List классов `Circle`. Откуда он знает как преобразовывать данные `int` в класс `Circle`?

Comment: Так а что же сделать?

Comment: Вы аналогии никакой не видите с другими фигурами в вашем коде?